# java gui window

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, window

I wrote a java code that finds frequencies of group of input values..
this is what the last part of the output should looks like.

Boundaries are :

Interval [11.5 - 27.5] contains : 2 number(s)

Interval [27.5 - 43.5] contains : 1 number(s)

Interval [43.5 - 59.5] does NOT contain elements

Interval [59.5 - 75.5] contains : 1 number(s)

Interval [75.5 - 91.5] contains : 1 number(s)

but when I tried to convert it to gui I had a little problem which is:
each line of the results is displaying in a new window.

this is the gui code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Frequency

{

private static ArrayList<Integer> FindNumbersInInterval(int[] array,double     startInterval,double endInterval)
{

    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>() ;

    for(int v: array)
    {
        if(v >= startInterval && v <= endInterval)
        {
            result.add(v);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(final String args[])
{

    int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    int range = 0;

    String numberOfNumbers =
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many numbers do you want to enter: ");
    int num=Integer.parseInt(numberOfNumbers);


    int array[]=new int[num];   




    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    {

    String theNumbers =
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the numbers now: ");

    array[i]=Integer.parseInt(theNumbers);

    {
        if(array[i] < smallest)

            smallest = array[i];

        if(array[i] > largest)

            largest = array[i];

    }

    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Smallest is "+smallest,"Smallest",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Largest is "+largest,"Largest",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);


    range = largest - smallest;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Range is "+range,"The Range",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

    String subInterval =
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of subinterval: ");
    int subnum = Integer.parseInt(subInterval);

    int subwid = range / subnum;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The width of subinterval is "+subwid,"width",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);



    double boundary = smallest - .5;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Boundaries are ","The Boundaries",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

    while(boundary < largest + .5)

    {

        double startInterval = boundary;

        double endInterval   = boundary + subwid;

        ArrayList<Integer> numbersInInterval = FindNumbersInInterval(array, startInterval, endInterval);

        if(numbersInInterval.isEmpty())

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Interval "+startInterval+" - "+endInterval+" does NOT contain elements","result",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        else {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Interval "+startInterval+" - "+endInterval+" contains "+numbersInInterval.size(),"result",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);


        }

        boundary += subwid;

    }

}
}
```

So, my question is how do I make group of results come in one window?

thnx..

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a different component to display in the JOptionPane.

Maybe you could use a JTextArea or JList to display individual lines of data.

Then you add that component to the option pane and display the option pane.

Read the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). It has section on each of the above components with working examples.

Answer (score 2):

You build up the String and only at the end display the result. For this create a `StringBuilder` (lets call it message) at the beginning of your method.

Then replace every call to `JOptionPane` with `message.append(<your text here>)`

At the very end call `JOptionPane` once with `message.toString()` as the argument

Alternatively you can display it in suitable component (JLabel / JTextfield) and set the text property. This can be done multiple times, so you can show results as soon as you have them. The component itself would be positioned in a Toplevel Window (JFrame or JDialog)

Comment: I would've used (JLabel / JTextfield) and action handlers but I don't know how to do some calculations on values taken from JTextfield.
about your first part how do I display it outside the loop, this way is easier than action handlers.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code to your main method:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
frame.add(contentPane);
```

The code creates a new JFrame and a JPanel with its layout set to [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html).

And this to the if statement of the last while loop

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Interval "+startInterval+" - "+endInterval+" does NOT contain elements");
contentPane.add(label);
```

Adds a JLabel to display the text.

And this to the else statement of the last while loop

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Interval "+startInterval+" - "+endInterval+" contains "+numbersInInterval.size());
contentPane.add(label);
```

And the final bit of code goes oafter the last while loop.

```
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Displays the JFrame.

And you can remove the following lines from your code:

```
. . .
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Interval "+startInterval+" - "+endInterval+" does NOT contain elements","result",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
. . .
```

and

```
. . .
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Interval "+startInterval+" - "+endInterval+" contains "+numbersInInterval.size(),"result",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
. . .
```